# Declaring a variable which has a value in c++ or c that does not get destroyed when the program terminates

Tags: c++, c

How can I declare a variable or array that contain a value which does not get destroyed when the program terminates in c or c++?

Comment: File I/O is what you are probably after

Comment: see [data hibernation for some clues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_(computing))

Comment: I think you should start with the Beginners section in [the book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3):

When the process terminates, the kernel releases the resources owned by it. If you want to keep data/information obtained during the runtime of the process, you can use a database or the file system.

Comment: how can I use a file system or database in c or c++?

Comment: Check this basic tutorial on File I/O: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep data after your process terminates, try storing it in a file.
check this for more:
[file handling in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-handling-c-classes/)